# UITextField must have minimum characters to activate UIButton

Tags: swift, uitextfield

`I am new to Xcode/Swift, and am unable to figure out how to make a UITextField require a minimum number of characters (e.g.- 7) before a UIButton is made active (e.g.- Next).

If the user does not enter at least 7 characters into the UITextField (e.g.- password field), the UIButton (e.g.- "Next") remains inactive.  However, when the user does enter 7 or more characters into the UITextField, the UIButton is activated and works as normal (clicks through to the next screen).

Below is my View Controller code.  The UITextField in question is "`passwordField`" and the UIButton is "`toViewController3`":

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

@IBAction func toViewController3(_ sender: Any) {
    print("button pressed")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController2ToViewController3Segue", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func backToViewController1(_ sender: Any) {
    print("back button pressed")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController2ToViewController1Segue", sender: self)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("ViewController2 has loaded")

    passwordField.delegate = self
    passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()

}

// Hide Keyboard when touch on screen
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    print("Keyboard Hidden by Screen Tap")
}

// Hide keyboard when Return key is pressed
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
    print("Keyboard Hidden by Return Key")
    return true
}

}

}
```

Comment: for back button press do not use segue its not a good practice instead `_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

Comment: @Museer - Thanks.

Comment: Welcome and happy coding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using target for `.editingChanged`

Create action which gets called when user types or deletes character from TextField (control event `.editingChanged`). Then set button's `isEnabled` property depending on if TextField's `text` has at least 7 characters.

```
...
textField.addTarget(
    self, 
    action: #selector(textFieldChangedValue(_:)), 
    for: .editingChanged
)
...

@IBAction func textFieldChangedValue(_ sender: UITextField) {
    yourButton.isEnabled = sender.text!.count >= 7
}
```

#### Using `RxSwift` library

If you are familiar with using `RxSwift` library, you can simply observe `rx.text.orEmpty` control property of `UITextField`, in `map` you can validate the text and then you can bind it to button's `rx.isEnabled` binder.

```
textField.rx.text.orEmpty
    .map { $0.count >= 7 }
    .bind(to: yourButton.rx.isEnabled)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Comment: How does the UIButton remain inactive until the minimal 7 characters have been entered?  And how does it get activated?

Comment: I added you code -and updated my original post to reflect as much, but am having a build error of 'Missing return in a function expected to return Bool'

Comment: @Eric don't forget to add `return true` (I have it in updated answer)

Comment: Thank you.  I changed the value from "7" to "6" in order to get the button to activate at 7 characters.  The button is active until the user begins using text field, at which point it deactivates, how can the button be made inactive from the get-go (prior to user touching inside text field)?

Comment: @Eric Just in viewDidLoad set `someButton.isEnabled = false`

Comment: @RobertDresler What happens if the field contains 8 characters then the user selects 5 of them and hits delete?  I think that if `string` is empty, you need to subtract the length of `range` rather than 1.

Comment: @Robert The user pressing the back button solution worked - thank you.  Interestingly, if user enters 6 or more characters and then clicks out of UITextField and back into UITextField, and types something, the UIButton remains active until the user types a second character.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jm74704l84lc4y/stackoverflow-UITextField%20must%20have%20minimum%20characters%20to%20activate%20UIButton.mov?dl=0

Comment: @PhillipMills thank you! This was problem that I hadn't thought about! Little experience...

Comment: @PhillipMills I just tried what you suggested above, and the UIButton behaved as it should (went inactive) when it had = 6 characters.  However, with 7 or more characters it did indeed fail/not behave correctly (was still active).

Comment: `shouldChangeCharactersIn` is not the best choice here. You don't want to check whether text should change, you want to do something when the text has changed. And that should be done by listening to `UIControl.Event.editingChanged`.

Comment: @Sulthan OMG, this makes it much easier... Thank you! :-)

Comment: @RobertDresler není zač :]

Comment: @RobertDresler Everything works correctly  Sulthan and PhilipMills great input!

Answer (score 0):

```
let text = UITextField()
text.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

@objc func textFieldChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text?.count > 7 {
        // active button
    } else {
        // disable button
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer, include an explanation how it addresses the problem of the question.